# Combinatorics - Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers

A game of indoor soccer is ended in 8-6 score for TEAM A.
It is known that TEAM B has not lead TEAM A at any point in the game.
How many different orders of goals being scored for each team are there?
(TEAM A scored = 0 , TEAM B scored = 1 - (00001111000011 - example) )

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please show us your efforts on the question to avoid it being closed or heavily downvoted. For formatting help, See: [Mathjax help page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). For future reference, I would request you to read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) page which will help you familiarize yourself with asking questions on this website. Thanks!

Comment: See the wikipedia page for Catalan Numbers (specifically the third proof using exceedance). It should let you find your result relatively easily.

Comment: Also see [André's reflection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem).